# MacOS dock icon in Libgdx 1.11

Tags: java, macos, libgdx

I would like my libgdx application to have a dock icon in macOS. This is the code that I tried, posted by fourlaster on discord:

```java
private static void updateDockIconForMacOs() {
    if (SharedLibraryLoader.isMac) {
        try {

            Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            // icon.png is in assets
            final URL imageResource = DesktopLauncher.class.getClassLoader().getResource("icon.png");
            final Image image = defaultToolkit.getImage(imageResource);
            Taskbar taskbar = Taskbar.getTaskbar();
            taskbar.setIconImage(image);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The icon did change, but my program hangs. No exceptions were thrown. I tried to execute this before and after the application was created, but still not working.